# My images are loading too late, why?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom

I have a few js and css files that loads on the `head`. After the last js file there is a gap (on Firefox) of `1311ms` until the browser starts to load the images.

[image: image loading too late]

Firebug doesn't show any status on this blank space.

What does it mean? Why are my images loading so late?

All images on cache, the gap is still there...

[image: gap]

Full no-cache load:

[image: huge gap]

Comment: I have seen this as well. Heck, I'm looking at a page of mine right now that does this! I always assumed it was caused by the time Firefox was taking to parse and load a javascript file.  Be curious to see your answers.

Comment: What are the images referenced by?

Comment: @SLaks what do you mean? The first image is just a static one... `<img src="" />`

Comment: It's weird, as it's taking the images from the cache.. I would also guess Firefox first finish "compiling" the client side script and CSS only then starts handling images. If you omit several JS files, does it affect the gap?

Comment: @Shadow The gap goes down, in the middle of the image requests...

Comment: @BrunoM, interesting situation here. How do you refer your images in HTML? Are they referred by CSS or JS? An image referred by CSS and JS will not be loaded until unless CSS and or JS comes into action. You must have noticed this for CSS based mouseovers. If that's not the case, did you try serving images from some other domain? Does that slows down image loading?

Comment: Happened across this article today, it discusses this gap: http://blog.teuntostring.net/2009/07/announcing-log-to-netpanel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 300kb JavaScript file. That's a lot of JS to parse and possibly execute. Try the profiling tool in Firebug or Chrome to see what JavaScript is being run on page load.

Answer (score 1):

there some maybe reason.

- Those static file in many HOST, these are not in the same HOST.
- Your browser is resolve these file slowly.
- A javascript file in these file spending much time.

you can use some web preformance tool, like Yslow, chrome console .. to analysis this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking img tags, then the delay might be the time it takes the browser to render the page. I'd have to look for a reference, but I recall that the browser doesn't start to fetch images until it has rendered the page. You could test this out by adding some profiling that shows when the page has completed rendering, and compare that to the time the first image starts loading. I have profiling inserted in my pages that inserts timestamps as the very first statement/element (inside the head), and the very last (in the body). Comparing the two gives you the approximate render time.